# Failed to connect to cc-clickhouse.ads.aliyuncs.com port 8443: Operation timed out

Tags: database, clickhouse, alibaba-cloud

When I'm trying to connect my ClickHouse instance on Alibaba Cloud with https protocol from my Mac, and this is the response error:

*Failed to connect to cc-xxxx.germany.ads.aliyuncs.com port 8443: Operation timed out*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBm93.png)

`curl --cacert ./Downloads/ClickHouse-CA-Chain.pem https://cc-clickhouseinstance.connection.string.ads.aliyuncs.com:8443/ping`

I have tried ping, and it shows ok, so what the problem would be?

How to connect ApsaraDB for ClickHouse instance on Alibaba Cloud using https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should check your instance security group, be sure the public IP of your PC is on the allow list.

If you don't know how to get your public IP, check below.
https://ip.taobao.com/ipSearch

Or you can switch to connect from ECS instances and put public IP or intranet IP on the list. Just like this
[Data Security Rules Configuration Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkAhE.png)

[Reference]
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/393349.htm